# Pattern rule of a lower diagonal region of a matrix

Tags: matrices, diophantine-equations, quadratics

I have a vector of numbers. Each number refers to the number of elements in the lower part of a square matrix, excluding the diagonal. For example, a 2-by-2 matrix would yield the number 1, a 3-by-3 matrix would yield the number 3.

So, the pattern is `{1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, ...}`. How could you back-calculate from this number the length of one side of the square matrix?

Note: I can't just calculate with a sequence, because there are missing elements, e.g. there wouldn't be a matrix with the square edge length of 450.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of elements along and above the diagonal of a matrix of size $n \times n$ is given by

$$
\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$

So, if $d$ is the number of elements below the diagonal you want to solve

$$
\begin{align}
n^2 - \frac{n(n+1)}{2} &= d\\
\implies n^2 - n -2d &= 0\\
\end{align}
$$

$$
\implies n = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 8d}}{2}
$$

You will just want the positive root so

$$
n = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 8d}}{2}
$$